# This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

So I noticed an answer that was entirely placed in code formatting, including information indented to be as text. So I edited the answer and fixed it. But I noticed that I had two rejects stating:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

The edit was accepted, although I did not understand the reasoning behind the reject. I don't see a reason why it would not of made sense as an edit. Could anyone clarify the reasoning behind them?

[Here is the information on the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5976612)

Comment: It's worth noting that adding slightly longer explanations (eg. "`Moved text out of code block and fixed inline code comment`") makes it much easier to review properly. The edit was fine, though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When looking at the diff in "rendered output" mode, at first sight it looks like you added a lot of text. Unless people notice the horizontal scrollbar in the output for the original version, it's not obvious that the content was all there, in enormously long lines:

[image: screenshot of diff]

The reviewers who rejected your edit most likely thought that you added all this text, which would mostly fall under the "Too Radical" rejection reason.

Comment: (This is also why it's good idea for reviewers to look at both rendered output and markdown; you can miss something like this that completely changes what you might've thought by looking only at one)

Comment: I hate the "rendered" diff for this reason. Very tempted to suggest disabling it - or at least forcing it to be chosen explicitly on each review.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd advocate the latter over the former; the rendered diff comes in handy when there's any sort of formatting change

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not convinced that forcing the markup mode is a good general solution. IMHO, for a large majority of edits, seeing the rendered output is just fine, and in fact the most efficient way of evaluating the edit. After all, you look at the post the same way everybody else sees it, and what matters is that the post is better for people reading it. Of course using the markup has the big advantage of clarifying the kinds of edits above, but those are much rarer, and markup is always quickly available when an edit looks fishy in the rendered diff.

Comment: @Shog9 The rendered view is good when the edit changes a link to a picture.