# Should this edit have been rejected as "does not improve the quality of the post"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Yesterday, I've [suggested an ordinary edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29457537) which I've done many times. I've added a missing inline code formatting, fixed some spelling mistakes, removed explicit line breaks within paragraphs (used as a word wrapping in question source), and added more tags.

Today my edit was rejected by 2/3 reviewers with the following reason:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

It may look like a mess, but the Markdown view makes things more clear.

Please tell me what I've done wrong or override this review.

Comment: In my opinion you overdid it a little, adding too much formatting and I really wonder if this question needs five tags. But that's the point: it's my opinion. Opinions are going to differ, and that will also mean that edit reviews are going to differ depending on who does the reviewing. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @Gimby - I think we have clear guidance on formatting identifiers as code, so I think the edit was all right in that department. But have to agree that added tags are debatable - need a Python SME here. P.s. And I would've accepted it too should I come across it in the queue.

Comment: I would have accepted your edit. It looks good to me. I agree with Gimby about the tags though. Those two tags were sufficient. Personally, I would have chosen ‘accept and edit’ to remove the extra tags

Comment: *It may look like a mess, but Markdown view makes things more clear.*  don't expect robo-reviewers to check your edit in the Markdown view. In side-by-side it looks like a generated review audit. Specially given the age of the post I won't blame the reviewers for picking reject. If anything I would refrain from fixing whitepace. That is non-sense, specially as your edit seem to remove the extra line there was before the last line of the post.

Comment: I personally didn't like that you removed the paragraphing on the post. Those made it an easier and more pleasant read. The rest seemed like a nice edit to me :)

Comment: Your edit doesn't make the post more readable than it already is to me, I'd reject as well.

Comment: @Sabito The two tags were _correct_, but I don't think there's such thing as too much tags (to the reasonable extent which is 5). First of all, more tags means more views, but I've added them because I want my answers to be properly tagged to accumulate tag badge stats. These tags are basically alternatives: `setuptools` is an extension to `distutils` and `setup.py` is used by both.

Comment: Isn't robo-reviewing an abuse, @rene? In that sense such audit better have an opposite expected reaction. ;-)

Comment: @EvgenKo423 See [Should I not add the relevant tags to a question if I have written an answer to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407618/should-i-not-add-the-relevant-tags-to-a-question-if-i-have-written-an-answer-to)

Comment: @Scratte I've tried to merge a few related paragraphs, because the post is long by itself and maybe even contains too much details (but well, I've respected the original author). I was in doubt about the second merge.

Comment: *"I've added them because I want my answers to be properly tagged to accumulate tag badge stats"* - that's not a reason to force tags to suit your needs. Tags are for ***questions***, not ***answers***

Comment: These tags are suitable for this question as I've explained above, @Tomerikoo. ;-)

Comment: Then why do you present it as your reason for tagging? The one and only reason for tagging should be *"those tags are relevant"* (which I dispute in this case), not *"I want to improve my tag score"*

Comment: And @Tomerikoo has explicitly explained why they explanation is wrong, EvgenKo423. It's fine to add tags that have been missed that the OP is asking about; for example the methodology the OP is asking about ([[tag:gaps-and-islands]] and [[tag:upsert]] come to mind as examples) but adding tags because *you* used those technologies in your answer, when the question isn't explicitly about them is wrong.

Comment: I'm  trying to get the feature-request tag here. Can someone add it? It is better for my score.

Comment: I feel that "X is an extension of Y" is a bit fishy reasoning for retagging – *lots* of things are extensions of others, yet often enough we need/want to make do with the smaller/simpler/builtin one. Seeing how the question was *explicitly* asked for ``distutils`` (back when ``setuptools`` just hit 1.0), adding a broader tool and even erasing the original one from the title seems to shift the focus of the question.

Comment: @Larnu, rene, it's **not only** about my score. I can understand that `setuptools` can be disputed, but it suites the question as well, not only my answer. `setuptools` is a drop-in replacement, it would work even if you didn't change any code and you can make my answer work with `distutils` just by replacing a library name (but that's not what reviewers are expected to know, of course).

Comment: But the OP isn't asking about [[tag:setuptools]] @EvgenKo423 , and the other answers aren't using setuptools. Are you saying that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772928/2029983) is wrong because it doesn't use the technology you tagged in the question? Unless the answer is "yes" then adding the tag is wrong.

Comment: I mean [these badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/578924), @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. ;-)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Agree, your point makes sense in general, but I doubt it's an issue with `setuptools`. As per title, I've removed it because it's in tags already and hence quite redundant.

Comment: @Larnu No, that answer will also work with `setuptools` and I didn't remove the `distutils`. So you're saying that only "and" modifier between tags is allowed while "or" is not?

Comment: Have a read of my answer on the [qusetion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407618/should-i-not-add-the-relevant-tags-to-a-question-if-i-have-written-an-answer-to) that was linked earlier, @EvgenKo423 .

Comment: I've read your answer, @Larnu, and as I've tried to explain multiple times it's not applicable here, because it doesn't make any present or future answer wrong or broken. Here's how things relate in this case: Suppose we have a Q with tags `windows` `windows-xp`. I wrote an answer for Windows XP and tested it on XP SP3. I then added a tag `windows-xp-sp3`. It won't break any of the answers and even if someone writes an answer compatible with XP SP3, but not SP0, (which is highly unlikely as SPs shouldn't bring any substantial changes) the OP was still asking for the whole Windows XP.

Comment: @Larnu However, it occurred to me today that when `distutils` will be dropped from standard library `setuptools` won't be a patch anymore, so it _is_ indeed a bit fishy situation as it _may_ result in answers incompatible with `distutils` or even `setuptools` in a future...

Comment: So you're saying that the question wasn't applicable to Windows XP SP2 and only applicable to SP3, @EvgenKo423 ? If so, then yes, you can edit the question. If, however, there is nothing in the question to suggest it is about SP3, then adding the tag is wrong.

Comment: @Larnu This rabbit hole is very deep... OK, this usage is probably incorrect, because the Q is not specifically about extension introduced by `setuptools`. But I'm genuinely confused now... You're basically suggesting that if someone asks a Q about things common to both `distutils` and `setuptools`, then the proper way is to tag it as `distutils`, even though it's outdated and not used by the author... Still all the previous attempts of the community to explain this were not helpful to me.

Comment: If the OP tagged incorrectly, you can remove said tags, @EvgenKo423 , but again, what I am *explicitly* stating is don't tag for the answers, tag for the question... That's what you're consistently missing.

Comment: No, Larnu, for me it's the _community_ consistently missing that I'm _not_ missing it, I'm not that type of person! I was adding tags _because_ I wrote an answer (the reason I pressed the Edit link) and there could be more tags relevant to both Q and A, but I did not intend to add tags relevant _only_ to A. I was sincerely thinking it _is_ relevant to both Q and A, because Q is about the code that `setuptools` inherited from `distutils` and both use `setup.py`. It's just not _that_ obvious as in the linked question; I guess it was as confusing for me as for you all. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your suggested edit has a number of good aspects but also some bad ones, and I can understand why the review received mixed responses.

Let's look at the good points, first:

1. The title change: adding "source" clarifies and removing "in distutils" is good, because that's implied by the question having [distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distutils).
2. Code formatting for instructions and flags.
3. Changing "gcc" to "GCC" is (IMHO) correct and a positive contribution.
4. Adding [setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setup.py) is definitely a positive, and [compiler-flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-flags) is likely useful, as well.

Now the negative points:

1. As rene has said, adding [setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setuptools) is inappropriate (only your answer references that).
2. In Para. #1, changing the ". (Some … .)" to " (some … )." is completely arbitrary (and may even be considered to go against the OP's intent).
3. The whitespace adjustments (also, as rene has mentioned) seem superficial, to me (and the last actually changes the paragraph breaks *chosen by the OP*).
4. You've missed a couple of possible other improvements/corrections: In Para. #4, "generate" should be "generate**s**" and, in Para. #6, there should be a comma after "Ideally".

So, by my (albeit subjective) reckoning, that's 4 good points *versus* 4 bad points – which is why I can understand the spilt vote. Personally, had I reviewed that, I would most likely have chosen the "Improve Edit" option, and reverted/corrected the bad points. That would also have 'unilaterally' approved your suggestion and given you the +2 reputation; others may have chosen "Reject and Edit" if they felt you didn't deserve the +2.

Comment: Thanks for your highly constructive answer. About negatives: 1. I've understood that I should've explained about the `setuptools` tag, but it's really just a bunch of wrappers around `distutils`, all answers will work with both modules. 2. I can understand that it's questionable, but I don't see how it changes the meaning in some way.

Comment: 3. As I've answered to rene, I just didn't like that line breaks are used to wrap words in question source, I wouldn't make an edit _just for that_, but I think it's worth fixing in advance. [Guidelines for reviewing First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/578924) (yes, not exact, but related) says: "**Common reasons to _edit_**: Not enough paragraph breaks, or too many".

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Yeah - the line-beak stuffs (except for the very last one) are, in themselves, not bad. They're also not especially necessary, so maybe that point could be moved either to "good" or "neutral".

Comment: I like the template of this answer for "why was this edit rejected" questions. Good first, what can be improved upon second. Designed to be easy to accept and still deliver the message. Minor gripe: there is no need to speak about reputation points really, just leave it out unless specifically asked about.

Comment: @Gimby Detailed breakdown is great for any "what's wrong with ..." type of things. Now it would be also good to see a _well-received question_ template. For example, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274297/11725753) was asked in a way similar to mine and had quite similar problem (not using the Markdown view), but it was received well, while mine was received as a blowout of critique on subject which people are not familiar with...

Comment: @EvgenKo423 This is meta, "well-received" is a very vague concept here since voting works quite differently. A heavily downvoted question on meta can still be very useful. The fact that this question got several answers and shows a lot of activity and interest implies to me that it is quite well-received as a meta post.

Comment: @Gimby Your explanation through activity looks good to me. However, from what I've read voting should be different only for feature requests and from what I've experienced on meta.SE voting there looks more standard (maybe because of an existing rep).

Answer (score 27):

You have made 21 whitespace changes on that post on a total of 34 changes. That is a heck of a lot of nothing to review. And some of those whitespace changes touched the paragraphs, combining them into one. I'm not thrilled by that.

[For reference: this what a reviewer might use to decide to approve / reject your edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxfsF.png)

I have doubts about the added setuptools tag. Didn't you add that because your answer uses setuptools? The question nor any of the other answers mention setuptools as far as I can see. But I'm not an SME so this point might be moot.

I'm not convinced that question really needed an edit and if it did I'm not convinced your edit was the best that could happen to that post. In that sense I can see why reviewers would conclude that this specific edit didn't improve the quality of that post and therefor deemed it to be unnecessary.

Comment: Well, on the other hand line breaks should not be used to wrap words, it makes the text harder to edit. Paragraph merges were intended, because they are related and the post is long (maybe even contains too much details, but well, I've respected the original author). I was in doubt about the second merge.

Comment: These tags are basically alternatives: `setuptools` is an extension to `distutils` and `setup.py` is used by both. I've added `setuptools` not because I've used it, but because it _should_ be used instead as `distutils` is outdated. I can understand that tags may be debatable, but the tag description says "Setuptools builds on Python’s distutils".

Comment: @EvgenKo423 in that case: Nobody knows your intent. the edit comment isn't really helping to understand that intent either.

Comment: Agree, but the reviewer's guide says "if in doubt – skip it" and I've expected a bit that people would read the tag description at least.

Comment: You're are trying to re-write history. I'm not sure that is a valid approach on this specific question.

Comment: *"I've added `setuptools` not because I've used it, but because it should be used instead as `distutils` is outdated."* - That's not how it works, `distutils` is _standard and native_, `setuptools` simply isn't. The question is asking about `distutils`, _not_ `setuptools`, by all means offer an answer for `setuptools`, but the question isn't about `setuptools` and shouldn't be tagged as such.

Comment: You've got me wrong, @Nick. `setuptools` is a drop-in replacement, it would work even if you didn't change any code and you can make it work with `distutils` just by replacing a library name. `distutils` is officially abandoned and is going to be dropped from the standard library in some future version, but that's really out of what reviewers are expected to know.

Comment: [Expecting reviewers to skip is a bit of a gamble](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1440051)

Comment: @EvgenKo423 *"that's really out of what reviewers are expected to know"* - Then you are expected to _explain_ it in your comment, so your comment was unacceptable for the changes that you wanted to make. If you want a reviewer to be able to review a change in your favour, they need to understand the change, if they don't then don't expect them to review it the way you want.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 This entire line of reasoning about ``distutils`` being outdated and ``setuptools`` being a drop-in replacement would work better if the question weren't from 2013! In the scope in which the question was asked, ``distutils`` *wasn't* about to be outdated and replaced.

Comment: @Nick You're right, but as you can see there's not enough space to do so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well, the first version of `setuptools` [was released back in 2006](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#history) and AFAIK it was designed as a drop-in replacement from day 1.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 No, what I can see is you didn't use any of the space that you had available, earlier today I reviewed an edit with a 300 character long revision comment, meanwhile yours uses a measly  42, and it uses those 42 uselessly as well, you don't need to tell us *"Improved formatting, spelling and clarity"* - that's obvious, the comment is for stuff that's _not_ obvious.

Comment: OK @Nick, I've got your point and I did read the post about what should be in edit comments some time before, but unlike usual comments there's a one-line field which quite encourages to be short and if what I wrote is useless then the whole field in its current form is quite useless as well.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 *"the whole field in its current form is quite useless as well"* - I am not going to disagree with that

Answer (score -6):

You did nothing wrong (from what I can see). That edit looks amazing. I am perplexed as to why it was rejected.

In situations like this, it might be worthwhile to involve a moderator via a custom flag. They can approve the edit and also check whether the reviewers mindlessly reject every edit.

Comment: that is a really bad unnecessary change, some smaller good eidts with alot of bad edits equals bad edit

Comment: @nbk There are different opinions. Some might say that if the edit didn't move the question from a gutter to a pedestal then it's a bad edit. I believe that as long as the edit doesn't break anything and contains at least a small improvement then it is a good one. I don't see this edit breaking anything and the tags look somehow related. I would approve it.

Comment: he asked why was he rejected, and i read your answer and disagree wuth itm  because the whole edit is very bad

Comment: That was my intent with this post, @Dharman. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/578924) says "If your edit was to address a **legitimate policy concern** (e.g. removing a signature, removing irrelevant tags, etc.), flag the post for moderator attention", but I don't see any policies in my edit so I don't wanna bother mods explicitly and I've made this topic.

Comment: @nbk "alot of bad edits" are line breaks, I guess? So, you think it's OK to use line breaks to wrap words in text? Or what else you find bad there?